# ConnectionTimeout: Connection timed out running elasticsearch in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, google-colaboratory, kibana

this is my code i it worked before with my last ip
but now with new ip and port it does not work. I tested anything about elasticsearch and elastic server is up and my data and index are available.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch



def URL_Extractor(post_titles):
    es = Elasticsearch(['http://95.217.208.18:1997'])
    index_name = 'url_index'
    for post_title in post_titles:
        query = {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "post_title": post_titles
                }
            }
        }

        result = es.search(index=index_name, body=query)

        post = result['hits']['hits'][0]
        post_permalink = post['_source']['post_permalink']

        print(f"Post permalink for {post_title}: {post_permalink}")

post_titles = ['نظام آموزشی ایتالیا.txt', "سفر به فرانسه", "سفر به آلمان"]

URL_Extractor(post_titles)
```

### :17: DeprecationWarning: The 'body' parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instead use individual parameters.
result = es.search(index=index_name, body=query)
WARNING:elastic_transport.node_pool:Node <Urllib3HttpNode(http://95.217.208.18:1997)> has failed for 1 times in a row, putting on 1 second timeout

ConnectionTimeout                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 26>()
24 post_titles = ['نظام آموزشی ایتالیا.txt', "سفر به فرانسه", "سفر به آلمان"]
25
---> 26 URL_Extractor(post_titles)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py in perform_request(self, method, target, body, headers, request_timeout)
197                 exception=err,
198             )
--> 199             raise err from None
200
201         meta = ApiResponseMeta(

ConnectionTimeout: Connection timed out

Comment: can you check `curl -k http://95.217.208.18:1997`